How would a metamaterial electrical transformer work?
Faraday's law of induction states that the electromotive force $\mathcal{\epsilon}$ around a closed path is equal to the negative of the time rate of change of the magnetic flux $\Phi_B$ enclosed by that path:
$$\mathcal{\epsilon}=-\frac{\mathrm{d} \Phi_B}{\mathrm{d} t}.\tag{1}$$
The negative sign in Eqn.$(1)$ is called Lenz's law: the polarity of the induced emf is such that it produces a current whose magnetic field opposes the change which produces it.
The magnetic flux is the integral of the magnetic field $\mathbf{B}$ over the surface enclosed by the path:
$$\Phi_B = \iint \mathbf{B} \cdot \mathrm{d} \mathbf{A}.\tag{2}$$
In a material with magnetic susceptibility $\mu$ a magnetising field $\mathbf{H}$ produces magnetic field $\mathbf{B}$ given by
$$\mathbf{B}=\mu\mathbf{H}.\tag{3}$$
Now I understand that there are metamaterials that are engineered so that near their resonant frequency their magnetic susceptibility $\mu<0$.
Does this mean that a solenoid with a metamaterial core disobeys Lenz's law?
If an electrical transformer has a metamaterial core with $\mu<0$ what happens to the law of energy conservation when the mutual inductance $M$ is negative?


I don't understand what you are asking. In both Equations (1) and (2) there is only the B field that enters. Even if in Equation (3) the $\mu<0$, nothing interesting ought to happen; the field inside the metamaterial might be the opposite sign than usual, but the energy transfer should be basically proceeding without being affected; the details would be affected, but not the final results.

Perhaps instead of positive power going forwards in time through the transformer there is negative power going backwards which amounts to the same thing?

Again, that makes no sense. You know from intuitive expectations that the energy must be flowing from mains to device through the transformer, which can always be done at the E and B level. Just because H might be the opposite direction does not mean that the energy is going the other way; the details can be very much changed, but the overall result must still be in the correct direction.
